# Creating a decision tree?

Tags: trees, enumeration, bdd

So I'm trying to split on an attribute "Color" that has possible values (Blue,Green,Red,Orange,Pink).

I'm splitting on [entropy](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~shapiro/EE596/notes/InfoGain.pdf) values, and the best split can either be Multi-Way 5, Multi-Way 4, Multi-Way 3, or Binary. For example:

```
5: (Blue, Green,Red,Orange,Pink)

4: (Blue, Green), (Red), (Orange), (Pink)
   (Green,Pink), (Blue),(Red),(Orange)

3: (Red,Orange), (Blue,Green), (Pink)
   (Red,Blue), (Green, Orange), (Pink)

2: (Blue,Green,Red), (Orange,Pink)
   (Pink), (Blue, Green, Red, Orange)
```

And so on. But how can I make a comprehensive list of all the possible splits? Is there a specific algorithm I could use? Or how would I even know how many max possible combinations there are with this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entropy of a given attribute is non increasing over  [refinement of partitions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Refinement_of_partitions). This means that the best possible partition is singletons (one value per set). This is the method used for discrete attributes in known algorithms such as ID3 or C4.5.

As a side note, the number of partitions is given by [Bell's number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).